# Ruby / Redis gem: change default connection parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redis

How can I change the default connection parameters for [redis](https://rubygems.org/gems/redis) gem?

For example, I want all instances of redis to connect to other host/port by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've searched for the answer for a while and found, that [`Redis::Client::DEFAULTS` hash](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redis/3.1.0/Redis/Client) is mutable.

So, you can put something like this

```
# list of options: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redis/3.1.0/Redis/Client
Redis::Client::DEFAULTS[:host] = 'mycoolapp.local'
```

to some initializer (i.e. `config/initializers/redis.rb`) in Rails or where you're doing initialization in your non-rails app.